# Cannot access directory through standard user even when permission is given

Tags: terminal, permission, folders

I have a directory that I need to use to launch my OpenVPN client in my Mac. It is copied from my Raspberry Pi server through SSH protocol with my root user in Terminal with SCP. However, I need the files inside the directory to be accessed through my standard permissions user account. In Terminal, I ran:

`chmod -R 777 /vpn/directory`

and I copied the directory to the desktop of my standard user account. However, when I double click the directory, it gives me the error:

```
The folder can't be opened because you do not have permission to see it's contents.
```

What do I do?

Comment: Can you please share the output of running `ls -ld /vpn/directory` command and `whoami` command.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema Here: `drwxrwxrwx  23 root  wheel  782 Jan  4 13:52

Comment: Check if you can you access the folder via Terminal.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema I can now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

When I ran:

```
chmod -R 777 /vpn/directory
```

What I actually ran was:

```
chmod -R 747 /vpn/directory
```

So, the group `wheel` had only `read` permission. I thought my standard account was not part of the group wheel and I ran

```
dscacheutil -q group | grep 'wheel' -A 4
```

To make sure. I got the output:

```
name: wheel
password: *
gid: 0
users: root 

--
name: wheel
password: *
gid: 0
users: root
```

However, after running:

```
chmod -R 777 /vpn/directory
```

I am now able to access the files I need.

Thank you very much.